# Add background color to fab button so the contrast is better

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I am working with angular's own material implementation and used the fab button with the tooltip function. It works great, but I want to have it like google's calender app on Android [image]

So how can I modify the code to add a white background and let the tooltip display even when there is no mouse on it? Do I have to write a new directive for the fab button or can I add another directive for this change?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the More Options demo available at https://material.angularjs.org/HEAD/demo/fabSpeedDial

It uses the `md-autohide="false"` and `md-visible="tooltipVisible"` attributes to setup whether or not the tooltips should be visible. Then, in the controller, it watches for the FABs `isOpen` variable to change and after a short delay (600ms), it sets `tooltipVisible` to true:

```
  // On opening, add a delayed property which shows tooltips after the speed dial has opened
  // so that they have the proper position; if closing, immediately hide the tooltips
  $scope.$watch('demo.isOpen', function(isOpen) {
    if (isOpen) {
      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.tooltipVisible = self.isOpen;
      }, 600);
    } else {
      $scope.tooltipVisible = self.isOpen;
    }
  });
```

As for the color of the tooltip, you should be able to add a custom CSS class to your tooltip, then use that class to change the background color. Something like:

```
md-tooltip.white-tooltip .md-content {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: It works for displaying, but when I over and move the mouse away the tooltip disappears....

Comment: @mimo - Indeed, it appears related to this current issue: https://github.com/angular/material/issues/7300